# Android : ExpantableList view issue after third level

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android

Expandable List view :

I'm trying to implement the scenario as depicted below by using an Expandable list view in android but after two level of normal expansion the third level expansion does not accommodate
correctly within the view.
I doubt if more then two level hierarchy is possible by using Expandable list view.
Please suggest  me with the same and let me know for any other alternatives for the same implementation.
[image: Expantable List view.]

[image]

Comment: yeah it is possible.You have to search for 3-level Expandable list view or 4-level Expandable list view depending upon your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial it will help you how to implement 4 level Expandable List view in android. http://www.sfonge.com/forum/topic/4-level-expandable-list. Let me know it is help you  or not.